# react-native-ble-plx not detecting all nearby devices

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

```
import {BleManager} from 'react-native-ble-plx';

const DeviceManager = new BleManager();

export const scan = function scan() {
    const subscription = DeviceManager.onStateChange((state) => {
        if (state === 'PoweredOn') {
          DeviceManager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log("error",error);
            }
            if (device !== null) {
                console.log("device found ----> [id,name]", device.id, device.name);
            }
          });
          subscription.remove();
        }
    }, true);
}
```

This is my code to scan for nearby devices. When I run the app, only my laptop is detected although there are other nearby devices (phones that support Bluetooth LE) with Bluetooth turned on.

Also for my laptop, only the device id is shown, and the device name is shown as null.

Is my code missing something to detect all nearby devices and all the data of detected devices?

Comment: Do your nearby devices perform an advertising?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that.

Comment: With a ble scan, you can only find devices which do a ble advertising. Your e.g. laptop does this. For testing you can install nrf connect app on one of your nearby devices and start an advertising.

Comment: do you fine solutions for that

Comment: @MohamdAlmhde I did not find a solution for this. I instead used Java to manage bluetooth functionalities.